# Dpkg returns odd errors

Tags: dpkg

I was upgrading my debian and after a while the package UDEV and DIRMNGR started to give me errors.

I tried to download deb separately and try to fix the error but it doesnt seem to be a simple one. Is it possible to install these two package manually or fix the problem around dpkg?

UDEV is returning:

> dpkg: error processing archive
>   /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-jTaHJP/0-udev_232-8_amd64.deb (--unpack): 
>   subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 1

and

DIRMNGR is returning:

> dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: dpkg: error: version '' has bad
>   syntax: version string is empty

http://pastebin.com/XvAZ38UF

Comment: Try this <http://osdir.com/ml/general/2016-12/msg23624.html workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with `dirmngr` has been reported as [#848413](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=848413) against `dirmngr`, which resulted in [#848422](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=848422) against `dpkg` where the bug actually is.

To fix things, you can downgrade `dpkg` to the version in `testing`; if you have the appropriate entries in your repositories:

```
apt-get install dpkg/testing
```

should do the trick.

The `udev` installation error is caused by missing features in the kernel you're running. The easiest way to fix that is to use an up-to-date Debian kernel — the safest option there is to install `linux-image-4.8.0-2-amd64-unsigned` currently (assuming you're on `amd64`), or `linux-image-amd64` *if* you've got a SecureBoot-enabled system. In your specific case, since you're running an OVH kernel, you need to find an up-to-date OVH kernel...

Comment: thanks, what about udev? what is the solution for that?

Comment: Oh yes, sorry — what kernel are you running?

Comment: 3.2.13-grsec-xxxx-grs-ipv6-64

Comment: Ah, I take it that's an OVH system! You need an updated kernel then.

Comment: you are right :) it is an OVH system. I need to check how they provide the kernel then. So far I just put the UDEV package in hold.

thanks for the rest!

Comment: I would suggest to install the `apt-listbugs` package. It displays a warning if there are known RC bugs against packages that are about to be updated.